# Remove/Hide duplicates from combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagrid, combobox

I have an application which has a datagrid which displays the data as the example below shows

```
        FundID ClientName FundName
          1      Client1    Arch1
          2      Client1    Build3
          3      Client2    Build2
```

In the data grid I have it displayed so that one client can have many funds.
However I have a combobox to allow the user to filter the results by a certain client. My Problem is clicking on the combobox brings up a list like this

```
           Client 1
           Client 1
           Client 1
           Client 1
           Client 2
           Client 2
           Client 3
```

I want to have my combobox not to display the duplicates. , While I've seen  a few code examples I was wondering are there any ways around it using the properties menu is vs2012 or any simple code methods

Just to clarify the issue a little more my main goal here is to find out is there a way I can use sql or some other way to edit what is displayed in the combobox while not effecting what is shown in the datagrid

Comment: Please provide some code, on how you fill your combobox. It might only be a missing distinct() method.

Comment: @Serv see this is the weird part , for the combobox I set the datasource to be "InventoryBindingsource" in the properties menu , and the display and value members to be "ClientName" But I cant find anywere I can specify to have it be distinct whereas for actually filling the datagrid i was able to use sql to set the funds to be distinct... Doing this means my fund Combobox is fine and only displays distinct values but I'm unsure how to replicate this for my client combobox as i need it to display the duplicate client names in the datagrid but not in the comboBox. Sorry I couldn't add screen

Comment: @serv shot but my rep isnt high enough to add pictures

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use group by at sql side. After using group by you will get only one name at time

group by ClientName

when you use group by you have to select only FundID and ClientName so you get unique name.

Comment: Tried usign group by and was getting an error saying I couldn't use it as there was no aggregate function , is there a way to put sl code simply for the combobox so as not to effect the datagrid ?

Comment: can i know sql query?

Comment: the query is SELECT DISTINCT 
            ClientName, Fund.FundName, FK_Fund, ISIN
            FROM  Client, Fund

Comment: thats the query to fill the datagrid which is fine but that displays duplicate client names (which is fine) but distinct fundnames (which is what I want) but I want the combobox to only display single values

Comment: if fundname is not require then just remove it will give u proper result

Comment: ok got it you are filling datagrid by same query. If you want also fill combobox then you have go for another query.

Comment: hi , I've added in the query successfully to the table but how do i assign the query to the combobox ? sorry I'm new to using sql and c# together

Comment: By this way you can
ds means your datatable 
        cmbCompName.DataSource = ds;
        cmbCompName.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
        cmbCompName.ValueMember = "Your ID colum";
        //cmbCompName.DataBind();
        cmbCompName.Enabled = true;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35733/discussion-between-utkarsh-and-user2546071)

Comment: have you seen in datatable ? what data are in datatable? the query result is as per your expectation?

Comment: if i run the query in query builder it returns the correct data howver the drop down still does not

Comment: can you post your code for fill combobox and see in your datatable when you fill the combobox.

Comment: Hey if you are using dropdown then you have to Uncomment
    cmbCompName.DataBind();

Comment: I uncommented and I am getting the following error :: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\KIIDCalculationSuite\Packages\KIIDCalcGUI\KIIDCalcGUI\KIIDCalcForm.cs 62 40 KIIDCalcGUI

Comment: is there an alternative ?

Comment: this is right way to bind data to combobox 
You can also refer this url
     http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/179880/I-want-to-ask-you-how-to-fill-combo-box-using-c-an